Java Spring Security - have issue 404 - The requested resource is not available
I have simple project Java Spring Starter Project, It is good to go all when export war and deploy on the Apache Tomcat Server with simple index file
But right after i do a few pom added dependencty spring security and mapping the SecurityFilterChain
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(
                    jwtAuthFIlter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
            );
    return httpSecurity.build();
}

The war file after deploy always show
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
and
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/projecsample/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
I've tried all the relevant error via StackOverFlow but none solved

The requested resource [/projecsample/] is not available is the app isn't started.
